# How to get device tokens as Apple Push Notification Service provider?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I would like to add support for sending Apple Push Notifications to a iOS app. This is a news app, so every time some important news event has occurred,  then I would like to broadcast a push notification to all users and devices where the app is installed.

According to the [Apple Push Notification Service documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html), in Figure 3-3 the Client App must send the device token to the Provider.

In order to be able to send Push Notifications to all devices where my app is installed, do I have to create a webservice which receives and stores device tokens from the client apps when they register for notifications? In order to send a push notification, I need a token and the payload. I want to send a push notification to all users, typically many thousand users. So how can I best get access to the device tokens so that I can send the push notification to all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes. You will have to make a web service for sending the push notifications to any of the devices that are using your app.** As far as the device tokens are concerned, you can get them through your code using this :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {
   // other setup tasks here....
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}

// Delegation methods
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];
    self.registered = YES;
    [self sendProviderDeviceToken:devTokenBytes]; // custom method
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}
```

You need to write this in your `AppDelegate.m`, this will fetch the device token needed to send the push notifications.

Also, you can store those tokens on some Database server for further usage in sending notifications. You can use these tokens the next time when you want to send some notifications to selected or all of the users.